# How to ignore certain values using Java comparator for sorting

Tags: java

I'm using Java Comparator for sorting in my code. How I can only sort by certain values, e.g., the values range from 1 to 1000, (default is 1000), but I only want ascending sort to show 1,2,3,4,5,1000..., and descending sort to show 5,4,3,2,1,1000....
How do I do this?
Thanks,

David

Comment: What values should get "ignored"?

Comment: 1000 needs to be ignored in this case

Comment: Yes, but how is that determined at run-time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparators below treat the value 1000 as always "greater" than everything else;  1000 will always sort last.  Any other values are sorted either ascending or descending.

```
class AscendingComp implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
    {
        if (o1.equals(o2))   return 0;
        if (o1.equals(1000)) return 1;
        if (o2.equals(1000)) return -1;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
class DescendingComp implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
    {
        if (o1.equals(o2))   return 0;
        if (o1.equals(1000)) return 1;
        if (o2.equals(1000)) return -1;
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
}
```

Edit:
This is not a general solution, but answers the specific question.  In a general solution you must pay attention to the contract of `equals()` and `compare()`, especially being sure not to return inconsistent comparison results. For example, if you're not careful and accidentally return, say +1 for `compare(a,b)` and `compare(b,a)` then the sort could get into an infinite loop.

Comment: This could be improved upon by having a `Set<T> ignoredValues` instead of hardcoding 1000, but I really like this method. Much more adaptable than my own.

Comment: That's good if `1000` is fixed and it's not the maximum of the items.

Comment: Yes, this could be much more general, but part of the SO way is to point the OP in the right direction and let them learn by adapting the solution to their situation.

Comment: Beware that using Collections.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(new AscendingComp()) won' work, though.

Comment: thanks a lot for such quick replies, I'm using one comparator both for ascending and descending sorting (not sure if it's possible): public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
   if (a == 1000)
    return 1;
   if (b == 1000)
    return -1;
   return a.compareTo(b);
  } no need for this: if (o1.equals(o2))   return 0; here above code will sort well ascending or not descending

Comment: @David Zhao: you need the test for equality. If you don't keeup it, the comparator is assymetric and doesn't respect the contract. It might cause incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sort by ascending and then by descending. And you can add the results to a `List`?

Or you can implement your own [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) which has a state inside and switches the direction if it reached the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values you don't want to sort in a first list and the values you want to sort in second one. Sort the second list, and then rebuild the full list by adding all the items from the first list in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one wya to do it. Note that I'm using inefficient structures. You could do it better with things other than LinkedLists!

```
List<Integer> ignoredValues = new LinkedList<Integer>();

ignoredValues.add(1000);

List<Integer> copy = new LinkedList<Integer>();
copy.addAll(original);
copy.removeAll(ignoredValues);
sort(copy);

original.retainAll(ignoredValues);

copy.addAll(original);
```